# Nodejs with postgres

Tags: javascript

I don't know how to access to an object from my js file. I'm using Nodejs and I want to access to the object name jsonData but i keep getting an error.

What i'm doing in my html file is that i call my object located in my js file like these:

var geodata = JSON.stringify({{jsonData}});

AND here is the code in js file:

```
/* GET Postgres JSON data */
app.get('/data', function (req, res, next) {
    var client = new Client(conString);
    client.connect();
    var query = client.query(new Query(shapefiles));
    query.on("row", function (row, result) {
        result.addRow(row);
    });   
    query.on("end", function (result) {
        const data = result.rows[0].row_to_json;
        res.render('shapefile', {
            jsonData: data 
        });
    });
});
```

The error i get is:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I simply want to access my jsonData object in my HTML doc.

Comment: The error message should tell you more details about where the unexpected identifier is.

Comment: This is what it tells:
var geodata = JSON.stringify([object Object]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsonData` is an object.

By putting it between `{{` and `}}` you are implicitly converting it to a string.

This results in `[object Object]` (the default result of running the `toString` method of an object.

You need to convert it to a JavaScript source code representation of an object. Happily, a JSON syntax is a subset of JavaScript literal syntax so you can use JSON.stringify for this.

```
    res.render('shapefile', {
        jsonData: JSON.stringify(data) 
    });
```

It's very unlikely that it is useful for you to have `geodata` be a string of JSON instead of a JavaScript object, so you probably want:

```
var geodata = {{jsonData}};
```